# My nodemailer workd fine on localhost but does not works while deployed

Tags: nodemailer

I made a node mailer to send an email during a contact form it works fine on localhost but not on the server when deployed. I tried every other aspect of this but nowhere. starter programmer so not that much perfect in this field so I need help kindly share responses for its solution I hope for answers Here is snippet of my code:-

```
 
 exports.sendMail =  function (res, req) {
   console.log("In Mail Service", res + " <---> ", req);
   var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     host: "smtp.live.com",
     port:587,
     auth: {
       user: "subrata@spineor",
       pass: "Subrata#321",
     },
   });
 
   var mailOptions = {
     from: "subrata@spineor",
     to: "muskan@spineor.com",
     subject: "A New Client!",
     text: "welcome to Mailer ",
     html: `<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
 
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Contacted us</title>
     <style>
         *,
         *::before,
         *::after {
             box-sizing: border-box;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
         }
 
         table {
             border-collapse: collapse;
             box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #e1e5ee;
             text-align: left;
             overflow: hidden;
             width: 100%;
         }
 
         thead {
             box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #e1e5ee;
         }
 
         th {
             padding: .5rem 1rem;
             text-transform: uppercase;
             letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
             font-size: 0.7rem;
             font-weight: 900;
         }
 
         td {
             padding: .5rem 1rem;
         }
 
         a {
             text-decoration: none;
             color: #2962ff;
         }
 
         .status {
             border-radius: 0.2rem;
             background-color: red;
             padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
             text-align: center;
         }
 
         .status-pending {
             background-color: #fff0c2;
             color: #a68b00;
         }
 
         .status-paid {
             background-color: #c8e6c9;
             color: #388e3c;
         }
 
         .status-unpaid {
             background-color: #ffcdd2;
             color: #c62828;
         }
 
 
         .amount {
             text-align: right;
         }
 
 
         tr:nth-child(even) {
             background-color: #f4f6fb;
         }
     </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
     <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 
         <!-- START HEADER/BANNER -->
 
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td align="center">
                     <table class="col-600" width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                         <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                 <td align="center" valign="top" background="white" bgcolor="#66809b"
                                     style="background-size:cover; background-position:top;height=" 400""="">
 
                                     <table class="col-600" width="600" height="200" border="0" align="center"
                                         cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 
                                         <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td height="40"></td>
                                             </tr>
 
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td height="50"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                     </table>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                         </tbody>
                     </table>
                 </td>
             </tr>
 
             <!-- END HEADER/BANNER -->
 
             <!-- START WHAT WE DO -->
 
             <tr>
                 <td align="center">
                     <table class="col-600" width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                         style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;">
 
                         <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                 <td align="center">
                                     <table class="col-600" width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0"
                                         cellspacing="0"
                                         style=" border-left: 1px solid #dbd9d9; border-right: 1px solid #dbd9d9;">
                                         <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td height="50"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td align="center">
                                                     <table>
                                                         <thead>
                                                             <tr>
                                                                 <th>Name</th>
                                                                 <th>Email</th>
                                                                 <th>Phone</th>
                                                                 <th>Query</th>
                                                             </tr>
                                                         </thead>
 
                                                         <tr>
                                                             <td>${res.name}</td>
                                                             <td>${res.email}</td>
                                                             <td>${res.phone}</td>
                                                             <td>${res.query}</td>
                                                             <td>
                                                         </tr>
                                             </tr>
 
                                     </table>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                         </tbody>
                     </table>
                 </td>
             </tr>
 
             <!-- END WHAT WE DO -->
 
             <!-- START FOOTER -->
 
            
         </tbody>
     </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
 
     </tbody>
     </table>
 </body>
 
 </html>`,
   };
 
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
     if (error) {
       console.log("mail send error", error);
     } else {
       console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
     }
   });
 };
```